# GeoProcessing Tool Parameter: CoordinateSystem vs SpatialReference

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, coordinate-system, python-2.7, python-toolbox

So I'm adding a couple tools to my python toolbox. Most of the time I just used CoordinateSystem and leave good enough alone. Today I tried SpatialReference and noticed the result is the same. The the dialog box comes up asking user to select a coordinate system.

I see the explanation of the data types in the docs are a bit different but it seems the result is the same. Is this just some left over quirk or is there some really nuanced difference?

Below is my PYT for clarity.

```
class Toolbox(object):
def __init__(self):
    """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
    .pyt file)."""
    self.label = "Custom Python Tools"
    self.alias = "CustomPythonTools"

    # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
    self.tools = [batchCAD2GDB]

class batchCAD2GDB (object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.category = "Data Processing"
        self.label = "Batch Cad to GDB Converter"
        self.description = "Creates a file gdb named CAD2FGDB.gdb at source folder, and converts any dgn/dwg files in source folder to a feature class datasets in CAD2FGDB."
        self.canRunInBackground = False

def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    # parameter0
    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Source Folder",
        name="source",
        datatype="DEFolder",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
    # parameter1
    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Reference Scale",
        name="referenceScale",
        datatype="GPDouble",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
    # parameter2
    param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
        displayName="Coordinate System",
        name="coordinateSystem",
        datatype="GPCoordinateSystem",
        parameterType="Required",
        direction="Input")
    params = [param0, param1, param2]
    return params

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True  # or False

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""
    return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""
    source = parameters[0].valueAsText
    referenceScale = parameters[1].value
    coordinateSystem = parameters[2].valueAsText
    import os
    # make a file gdb in source
    arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(source, "CAD2FGDB.gdb")
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(source):
        for fname in files:
            if fname[-3:] in ['dgn', 'dwg']:
                for i in ["-", " ", "(", ")"]:  # check for illegal characters in name
                    if i in fname:
                        oldName = root+"\\"+fname
                        newName = root+"\\"+fname.replace(i, "_")
                        os.rename(oldName, newName)  # rename file if illegal characters found
                        cadFile = newName
                        outName = newName[:-4]
                    else:
                        cadFile = root+"\\"+fname
                        outName = fname[:-4]
                outGDB = source+"\\CAD2FGDB.gdb"
                arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(cadFile, outGDB, outName, referenceScale, coordinateSystem)
```

Comment: I think it may be helpful if you can create a test Python toolbox that illustrates just what you are describing here, and then include the code so that we can run it to try and reproduce.

Answer (score 4):

The spatial reference includes a **coordinate system** for x-, y-, and z-values as well as tolerance and resolution values for x-, y-, z-, and m-values.

So spatial reference is inclusive of coordinate system.

In the context of GP tool parameter, It seems they don't make a difference. The GUI doesn't let the user enter the tolerance and resolution! Probably The spatial reference takes the defaults (XY Tolerance = 0.001, XY Resolution = 0.0001)

This is the case with "Create Feature Class" tool. This tool uses coordinate system parameter and doesn't let the user enter tolerance or/and resolution.

---

The **resolution** represents the detail in which a feature class records the location and shape of geographic features. It is the minimum distance, in map units, that separates unique x-values and unique y-values in the feature coordinates.

A spatial reference also includes **tolerance** values. X-, y-, z-, and m-coordinates all have associated tolerance values that reflect the accuracy of the coordinate data. The tolerance value is the minimum distance between coordinates